# How to load a module before another loads in the same file in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

I'm trying to implement some features of Protobuf and I have a case: A module needs to call another module in compiling time. They are in the same file and it's hard to ensure their order.

```
defmodule FakeProtobuf do
  defmacro __using__(opts) do
    quote do
      # register_attribute fields and set fields
      @before_compile FakeProtobuf
    end
  end

  defmacro __before_compile__(_) do
    # result = Enum.map(fields, fn ...)

    # even Code.ensure_loaded doesn't work
    result = %{bar: Bar.default}
    quote do
      def default do
        unquote(Macro.escape(result))
      end
    end
  end
end

defmodule Foo do
  use FakeProtobuf
  # field :bar, type: Bar
end

defmodule Bar do
  def default do
    "bar"
  end
end
```

Some macro details related to fields are ignored in this piece of code, but the main idea is like what I said above. This code can't be compiled because Bar is not available when Foo is compiled even when `Code.ensure_loaded(Bar)` is called. I need this because I want to run some code in compiling time instead of runtime to save some time.

It works if Bar is defined before Foo or in another file. But it's hard to ensure this in protobuf generated files.

Is there anyway to solve this?

Comment: I haven't done much with compile order. Would `require Bar` be at all helpful? I don't know what exactly it does, but with what it does for macros, I would assume it would work here.

Comment: Yeah, `require` is the only way as far as I can tell from recent experimentation with `Code.ensure_loaded` and `require`, the former doesn't always work

Answer (score 0):

I can get your code to compile by simply defining `Bar` before the other modules.

When the compiler starts compiling your module `FakeProtoBuf` it has no knowledge about the definitions inside that module.

It starts compiling the file and encounters your `__before__compile/1` macro. When expanding that macro it needs to call a function in the module `B`, which the compiler has not yet seen, so it errors out on that.

```
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Bar.default/0 is undefined (module Bar is not available)
```

To solve this problem we move the `Bar` module before the definition of the `FakeProtoBuf` module. This way the compiler can safely call that function because `Bar` will be completely compiled.

And then finally the compiler will compile `Foo`, which will execute `__using__/1` in `FakeProtoBuf`, which will inject `@before_compile`, and thus call the macro `__before__compile__` in the `FakeProtoBuf` module.

```
  def default do
    "bar"
  end
end

defmodule FakeProtobuf do
  defmacro __using__(_opts) do
    quote do
      # register_attribute fields and set fields
      @before_compile FakeProtobuf
    end
  end

  defmacro __before_compile__(_) do
    result = %{bar: Bar.default()}

    quote do
      def default do
        unquote(Macro.escape(result))
      end
    end
  end
end

defmodule Foo do
  use FakeProtobuf
  # field :bar, type: Bar
end
```

Comment: But the problem is it's a little hard to guarantee the modules order, because the code is generated.

Comment: Then that is your problem, honestly. Fix the thing that generates the code. Or put them in seperate files.